# Debug NetSuite Restlet Service and Return error code "SESSION_TIMED_OUT" with postman, any idea where I go wrong?

Tags: cookies, postman, netsuite, restlet, suitescript

I wanna debug my Restlet Script and I follow the guide by the official document [Debugging a RESTlet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2980262.html)

But I could not get the expected results, below has 2 screenshots,
one is my success request with the Authentication header,
The other one is my problem with the "SESSION_TIMED_OUT" error.

[image: success request]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any tips/ help and regards!

Answer (score 0):

By inspiration in the bellow image, I choose to update my domain and I succeed in debugging Restlet Script
[image]

[Original Link](https://www.netsuiterp.com/2019/01/restlet-debugger-invalidhost-invalid.html)